# Firebase Realtime Database can you remove Listener when Listener is called

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I am using Firebase Realtime Database and I want to remove a listener as soon as a certain criteria is met. Here is my code:

```
final DatabaseReference forRequests = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common.requests + "/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid());

   listenForRequests = forRequests.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            pickuprequest.riderUID = (String) dataSnapshot.child(Common.riderUID).getValue();
                if (pickuprequest.riderUID != null) {
                        forRequests.removeEventListener(listenForRequests);
                        showRequestOnMap(forRequests);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
        }
    });
}
```

listenForRequests is a global variable. Just wondering if this code will work, or if there are any better solutions to this as I feel like it is very hacky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really tell what exactly your condition is really trying to express, but if you want just a single value a single time from the database (without listening to its changes over time), you can simply use [addListenerForSingleValueEvent()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#addListenerForSingleValueEvent(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)) to get a single snapshot of a node in the database.

If you're waiting for a value to appear that wasn't previously there, and you want to stop listening at the time it appears, what you're doing is fine.  But you might want to listen more closely to the child of interest instead of its parent.

Comment: Yup I am trying to wait for a value that wasn't there before to appear. I was just worried that deleting a listener while it was being executed is bad, or that because the listener is a final variable it wouldn't work.  Anyways thanks!

Comment: You can remove a listener any time you want.  It's never wrong to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks pretty idiomatic to me when you want to wait for a specific value.

In fact, the code in my [gist on waiting for an initial value](https://gist.github.com/puf/146fecdae240ac0e62f858f7650aa85f) is pretty similar:

```
mListener = ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            System.out.println("The value is now "+snapshot.getValue());
            ref.removeEventListener(mListener);
        }
    }
    ...
```